# How can I replace matched strings from regular expression with those matched strings modified

Tags: python, regex

Let us take an example from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

phone = "2004-959-559 # This is Phone Number"

# Delete Python-style comments
num = re.sub(r'#.*$', "", phone)
print "Phone Num : ", num
```

Here, let us say that instead of removing the comments, I just want to replace those comments with modified matched text. For example, replacing the Python style comments with C style comments, so that `# This is Phone Number` becomes `/* This is a Phone Number */`. How would I do that?

Comment: Using capturing groups?

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'#(.*)$|\D', lambda x: " /* {} */".format(x.group(1)) if x.group(1) else "",  phone)`

Comment: You may use: `re.sub(r'#(.*)$', r'/* \1 */', phone)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a capture group and a back-reference in replacement string:

```
>>> phone = "2004-959-559 # This is Phone Number"
>>> print re.sub(r'#(.*)$', r'/* \1 */', phone)
2004-959-559 /*  This is Phone Number */
```

- `(.*)` captures string after `#` in first capture group.
- `\1` is back-reference of the 1st capture group in matching regex in `re.sub`.
- You must use raw string mode in replacement in order to interpret `\1` properly.

Comment: So for any group, I need to surround it by brackets? Secondly, what does $ mean here?

Comment: `$` is a zero width anchor to match end of string and that is what you had in your question as well. For capture group, yes you need to enclose the pattern in `(` and `)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment example, str.replace should work for you:

```py
>>>
>>> str1 = "# This is a Phone Number"
>>> str2 = str1.replace("#", "/*") + " */"
>>>
>>> str2
'/* This is a Phone Number */'
>>>
```

Comment: I know a simple replace would do, but I just gave an example for learning purposes.